# Using flatMap in pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service which extends another service. I'd like to override the `all` method to behave differently in this service.

The problem I'm having is I'd like to manipulate the data I get and I only want the `data` value in the array I'll return.

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, myService);
  }
  
  all(arg1, arg2) {
    return super.all(limit, filter).pipe(
      flatMap((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // [{data: [1, 2, 3]}, {data: [4, 5, 6]}]
        // expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        return of();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for extending and overriding?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can see the desired output in the code

Comment: instead of flatMap of rxjs you can use of javascript because the data you are already getting is not observable now you can use `pipe(map((result) => result.flatMap(x=>x.data)))`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want array's flatMap method rather than RxJS's flatMap operator
*(which is an alias of RxJS's mergeMap operator)*.

Maybe something like this?

```ts
all(arg1, arg2) {
  return super.all(arg1, arg2).pipe(
    map(data => data.flatMap(v => v.data))
  );
}
```